# How to parse XML cell to multiple records without a variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have xml data stored as nvarchar in a table. I run a query to get data to a variable and parse the variable to multiple rows

```
declare @contenttable table(id int, xdata nvarchar(max))
insert into @contenttable values(1,'
<root>
<group Description="firstgroup">
    <nodeA age="10" birthplace="Anchorage"/>
    <nodeB mode="A" ability="read"/>
</group>
<group Description="nextgroup">
    <nodeA age="10" birthplace="London"/>
    <nodeB count="2" birthplace="Paris"/>
</group>
</root>')

declare @xml xml

select @xml = xdata from @contenttable where id=1

select
        c.value('@Description', 'varchar(max)') as 'Description'
from @xml.nodes('/root/*') as T(c)
```

The result is (The real scenario is more close to [How to get XML subnodes as strings along with parent attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54790755/how-to-get-xml-subnodes-as-strings-along-with-parent-attributes))

```
Description
===========
firstgroup   
nextgroup
```

Is it possible to get the result with only one select (without a variable)?

Comment: Well, you can simply join with that table and replace `@xml` with the column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the variable name with the column's, and include the table in your `FROM`:

```
SELECT c.value('@Description', 'varchar(max)') AS Description
FROM @contenttable ct
     CROSS APPLY ct.xdata.nodes('/root/*') T(c);
```

*Note, the **assumes** you change your datatype of your column to `xml`. XQUERY doesn't work on `(n)varchar` datatypes.*

```
SELECT c.value('@Description', 'varchar(max)') AS Description
FROM @contenttable ct
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(TRY_CONVERT(xml,ct.xdata))) V(xdata)
     CROSS APPLY V.xdata.nodes('/root/*') T(c);
```

Comment: Considering it's storing XML data, I would strongly recommend you change it's datatype @IvanH. Otherwise you'll be able to store invalid XML in the column, and that'll cause you far more problems down the line.

Comment: You *could* wrap the column in a `TRY_CONVERT` in a `VALUES` clause, but that means doing it **every** time you want to use XQUERY on that column. Always choose an appropriate datatype for your data, and for XML data the appropriate type is the (appropriately named) `xml` datatype.

Comment: The column was created in year 2002. The query in the question is part of change. It  will run only once per database. Performance is to a problem. I only want it to look 'nicer'. Could you, please, elaborate a bit more the idea of TRY_CONVERT.

Comment: I've added an extra version for you @IvanH. Even if the database was created in 2002, you're using SQL Server 2012, and the `xml` datatype was introduced in SQL Server 2005. Note that if the `TRY_CONVERT` fails, due to invalid XML data, then `NULL` will be returned. You may also note performance issues, due to the `TRY_CONVERT`.